# Python jmespath expression to return value if is is a string, if it is an array to a ',' join on it

Tags: python, jmespath

I have an attribute on a dictionary that I want to extract as a string. It can either come in as a string, or an array of strings. If it is an array, I would like to join all the elements together using `,` as the delimiter. What would that `jmespath` expression look like? Something like

`if type(field) == 'string' return field else if type(field) == 'array' join(',', field)`

Comment: Why don't you do this in Python after you convert the JSON to a structure?  In Python, it's `return field if isinstance(field,str) else ','.join(field)`.

Comment: I was wanting to just use a jmespath expression to do it for me instead of having to then do it after I get the value.

Comment: The jmespath expression is not going to be quicker.

Answer (score 0):

The query below does what you want

```
*.join(',', to_array(@))
```

The function [to_array](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#to-array) converts a string to an array and leaves an array as is. For example, given the dictionary

```yaml
{"k1": "x",
 "k2": "x",
 "k3": ["x", "y", "z"]}
```

the query

```
*.to_array(@)
```

gives

```yaml
[['x'], ['x'], ['x', 'y', 'z']]
```

Then use the function [join](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#join). Multiple items will be concatenated and single items will be simply extracted

```
*.join(',', to_array(@))
```

gives

```yaml
['x', 'x', 'x,y,z']
```

---

Example of a complete script for testing

```
shell> cat test.py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import jmespath


d = {"k1": "x",
     "k2": "x",
     "k3": ["x", "y", "z"]}

r = jmespath.search("*.to_array(@)", d)
print(r)

r = jmespath.search("*.join(',', to_array(@))", d)
print(r)

r = jmespath.search("join(',', to_array(k1))", d)
print(r)

r = jmespath.search("join(',', to_array(k3))", d)
print(r)
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ./test.py
[['x'], ['x'], ['x', 'y', 'z']]
['x', 'x', 'x,y,z']
x
x,y,z
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. For anyone who faces a similar problem, as an example if you have the dictionary `{"some_field": ["one", "two"]}` and you want to have the returned value be "one,two" , the following expression will work:

```py
>>> data = {"some_field": ["one", "two"]}
>>> expression = "to_array(some_field) | join(',', @)"
>>> jmespath.search(expression, data)
'one,two'
>>> data["some_field"] = "one"
>>> jmespath.search(expression, data)
'one'
```